# How can I add title text to this chart in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm following this tutorial for a D3 Circle Pack chart. https://bl.ocks.org/denjn5/6d5ddd4226506d644bb20062fc60b53f

How can I add the text from the ID column of the CSV to each circle?

[image: circles]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `circle`, you can create a `group` and have a `circle` and a `text` inside it.

So instead of:

```
// Draw on screen
vSlices.attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', function (d) { return d.r; });
```

You would do:

```
var gNode = vSlices
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

gNode.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
  return d.r;
});

gNode
  .append("text")
  .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.id;
  });
```

Notice that the translation is being done in the group and the attributes are different.

I hope it helps.